# Using a php to open a page after html has been added

Tags: javascript, php

I am running a php code that handles a form and sends you to another page. I am currently using this code as an example once my handling has been done:

```
echo "Success, redirecting to <a href = "index.html">index.html</a>";
//I then do some stuff with the session here
echo "<script>window.open('index.html', '_self')</script>";
```

I feel like this is not the most efficient way of running things. Is it possible to open the new page with plain php? (header location whatever doesn’t work because the first echo line defines the page).  Or, is there a way to do the same thing with header location whatever and displaying the earlier echo line differently, but still having the same effect?

Comment: You are correct that you can't use `header()` after you have outputted to the DOM. What exactly is the desired result? That the user is shown a *`"Please wait, redirecting"`* message for a few seconds, and *then* gets redirected?

Comment: I didn’t need a timeout, I just wanted that to be displayed in case there is an error or it takes a long time. But this works I just wasn’t sure if there was a better php way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with PHP after data has been sent back to the browser.

I would personally just add a `setTimeout()` in JavaScript and then run the `window.open()` after 5000ms.